# Use limitTo with ng-bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-bind

This may be an easy one but I can't get the below to work;

```
<span class="meta-content" ng-bind="data.weekdayot + ' - ' + data.weekdayct | limitTo: 5"></span>
```

However the below works as expected;

```
<span class="meta-content" ng-bind="data.weekdayot | limitTo: 5"></span>
```

For both lines of code I get `12:00`.
I want to get `12:00 - 21:00`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNwld4UjaxnPsRUU91Nv?p=preview):

```
<span class="meta-content" ng-bind="(data.weekdayot | limitTo:5) + ' - ' + (data.weekdayct | limitTo: 5)"></span>
```